# Defining non-unary functions in Cubical mode

Tags: agda, topology, cubical-type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'd like to define a function with two, higher inductive typed, arguments in Cubical mode. I am using [the `cubical` package](https://github.com/agda/cubical) as my "prelude" library.

I first define a quotient type for integers as a HIT:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
module _ where

open import Data.Nat renaming (_+_ to _+̂_)
open import Cubical.Core.Prelude

data ℤ : Set where
  _-_ : (x : ℕ) → (y : ℕ) → ℤ
  quot : ∀ {x y x′ y′} → (x ℕ+ y′) ≡ (x′ ℕ+ y) → (x - y) ≡ (x′ - y′)
```

I can then define a unary function using pattern matching:

```
_+1 : ℤ → ℤ
(x - y) +1 = suc x - y
quot {x} {y} prf i +1 = quot {suc x} {y} (cong suc prf) i
```

So far, so good. But what if I want to define a binary function, such as addition?

First, let's get the boring arithmetic proofs out of the way:

```
import Data.Nat.Properties
open Data.Nat.Properties.SemiringSolver
  using (prove; solve; _:=_; con; var; _:+_; _:*_; :-_; _:-_)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality renaming (refl to prefl; _≡_ to _=̂_) using ()
fromPropEq : ∀ {ℓ A} {x y : A} → _=̂_ {ℓ} {A} x y → x ≡ y
fromPropEq prefl = refl

open import Function using (_$_)

reorder :  ∀ x y a b → (x +̂ a) +̂ (y +̂ b) ≡ (x +̂ y) +̂ (a +̂ b)
reorder x y a b = fromPropEq $ solve 4 (λ x y a b → (x :+ a) :+ (y :+ b) := (x :+ y) :+ (a :+ b)) prefl x y a b

inner-lemma : ∀ x y a b a′ b′ → a +̂ b′ ≡ a′ +̂ b → (x +̂ a) +̂ (y +̂ b′) ≡ (x +̂ a′) +̂ (y +̂ b)
inner-lemma x y a b a′ b′ prf = begin
  (x +̂ a) +̂ (y +̂ b′)   ≡⟨ reorder x y a b′ ⟩
  (x +̂ y) +̂ (a +̂ b′)   ≡⟨ cong (x +̂ y +̂_) prf ⟩
  (x +̂ y) +̂ (a′ +̂ b)   ≡⟨ sym (reorder x y a′ b) ⟩
  (x +̂ a′) +̂ (y +̂ b)   ∎

outer-lemma : ∀ x y x′ y′ a b  → x +̂ y′ ≡ x′ +̂ y → (x +̂ a) +̂ (y′ +̂ b) ≡ (x′ +̂ a) +̂ (y +̂ b)
outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a b prf = begin
  (x +̂ a) +̂ (y′ +̂ b)   ≡⟨ reorder x y′ a b ⟩
  (x +̂ y′) +̂ (a +̂ b)   ≡⟨ cong (_+̂ (a +̂ b)) prf ⟩
  (x′ +̂ y) +̂ (a +̂ b)   ≡⟨ sym (reorder x′ y a b) ⟩
  (x′ +̂ a) +̂ (y +̂ b)   ∎
```

I now try to define `_+_` using pattern matching, but I have no idea how to handle the "points in the center of the face", so to speak:

```
_+_ : ℤ → ℤ → ℤ
(x - y) + (a - b) = (x +̂ a) - (y +̂ b)
(x - y) + quot {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₂ j = quot {x +̂ a} {y +̂ b} {x +̂ a′} {y +̂ b′} (inner-lemma x y a b a′ b′ eq₂) j
quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ i + (a - b) = quot {x +̂ a} {y +̂ b} {x′ +̂ a} {y′ +̂ b} (outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a b eq₁) i
quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ i + quot {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₂ j = ?
```

So basically what I have is the following situation:

```
                 p   Xᵢ
         X  ---------+---> X′

                 p₀  i
   A     X+A --------\---> X′+A
   |     |           |
  q|  q₀ |           | qᵢ
   |     |           |
Aⱼ +    j+          [+]  <--- This is where we want to get to!
   |     |           |
   V     V       p₁  |
   A′    X+A′ -------/---> X′+A′
                     i
```

with

```
X = (x - y)
X′ = (x′ - y′)
A = (a - b)
A′ = (a′ - b′)

p : X ≡ X′
p = quot eq₁

q : A ≡ A′
q = quot eq₂

p₀ : X + A ≡ X′ + A
p₀ = quot (outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a b eq₁)

p₁ : X + A′ ≡ X′ + A′
p₁ = quot (outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a′ b′ eq₁)

q₀ : X + A ≡ X + A′
q₀ = quot (inner-lemma x y a b a′ b′ eq₂)

q₁ : X′ + A ≡ X′ + A′
q₁ = quot (inner-lemma x′ y′ a b a′ b′ eq₂)
```

I am using [this construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199767/477476) to push out `q₀` horizontally by `i`:

```
slidingLid : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {a b c d} (p₀ : a ≡ b) (p₁ : c ≡ d) (q : a ≡ c) → ∀ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i
slidingLid p₀ p₁ q i j = comp (λ _ → A)
  (λ{ k (i = i0) → q j
    ; k (j = i0) → p₀ (i ∧ k)
    ; k (j = i1) → p₁ (i ∧ k)
    })
  (inc (q j))
```

and using this, my attempt at `+` is as follows:

```
quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ i + quot {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₂ j = Xᵢ+Aⱼ
  where    
    X = (x - y)
    X′ = (x′ - y′)
    A = (a - b)
    A′ = (a′ - b′)

    p : X ≡ X′
    p = quot eq₁

    q : A ≡ A′
    q = quot eq₂

    p₀ : X + A ≡ X′ + A
    p₀ = quot (outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a b eq₁)

    p₁ : X + A′ ≡ X′ + A′
    p₁ = quot (outer-lemma x y x′ y′ a′ b′ eq₁)

    q₀ : X + A ≡ X + A′
    q₀ = quot (inner-lemma x y a b a′ b′ eq₂)

    qᵢ : ∀ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i
    qᵢ = slidingLid p₀ p₁ q₀

    q₁ : X′ + A ≡ X′ + A′
    q₁ = quot (inner-lemma x′ y′ a b a′ b′ eq₂)

    Xᵢ+Aⱼ = qᵢ i j
```

But this fails with the following type error:

> ```
> quot (inner-lemma x′ y′ a b a′ b′ eq₂) j !=
> hcomp
> (λ { i ((~ i1 ∨ ~ j ∨ j) = i1)
>        → transp (λ j₁ → ℤ) i
>          ((λ { i₁ (i1 = i0) → q₀ eq₁ i1 eq₂ j j
>              ; i₁ (j = i0) → p₀ eq₁ i1 eq₂ j (i1 ∧ i₁)
>              ; i₁ (j = i1) → p₁ eq₁ i1 eq₂ j (i1 ∧ i₁)
>              })
>           (i ∨ i0) _)
>    })
> (transp (λ _ → ℤ) i0 (ouc (inc (q₀ eq₁ i1 eq₂ j j))))
> of type ℤ
> ```

One hint to what might be going wrong is that while these three sides degenerate nicely:

```
top : ∀ i → qᵢ i i0 ≡ p i + q i0
top i = refl

bottom : ∀ i → qᵢ i i1 ≡ p i + q i1
bottom i = refl

left : qᵢ i0 ≡ q₀
left = refl
```

the rightmost side doesn't:

```
right : qᵢ i1 ≡ q₁
right = ? -- refl fails here
```

I guess because `qᵢ` is pulled from the left side, so there could still be a hole between the right side and the pushed-all-the-way `qᵢ`, i.e. this would still be possible, with a hole at `O` between `qᵢ i1` and `q₁`:

```
                 p₀
      X+A ------------> X′+A
       |               /|
    q₀ |              / | q₁
       |             |  |
       |             | O|
       |              \ |
       V         p₁    \|
      X+A′ -----------> X′+A′
```

and intiutively it makes sense, because `q₁` is some algebraic statement about natural numbers, and `qᵢ i1` is a continuously deformed version of a different algebraic statement about different natural numbers, so there still has to be some kind of connection made between the two; but I don't know where to start on making that connection (i.e. constructing explicitly the 2-path between `qᵢ i1` and `q₁`)

Comment: A note on readability, `qᵢ` and `q₁` look very much alike, I mistook it for some kind of typo at first when I saw them in the expression `qᵢ i1 ≡ q₁`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there really **was** a possibility of a hole between `qᵢ i1` and `q₁` with the formalization I've been trying to do. The solution hit me when I  went back to [the HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) to try and solve this more abstractly for all quotient types, not just this particular `ℤ` type. To quote from section 6.10:

> We can also describe this directly, as the higher inductive type A/R
>   generated by
>
> - A function `q : A → A/R`;
> - For each `a, b : A` such that `R(a, b)`, an equality `q(a) = q(b)`; and
> - The 0-truncation constructor: for all `x, y : A/R` and `r,s : x = y`, we have `r = s`.

So what I was missing was that third point: that the lack of higher-typed structure is something that needs to be explicitly modeled.

Using this information, I have added a third constructor to my `ℤ`:

```
Same : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ → ℕ → Set
Same x y x′ y′ = x +̂ y′ ≡ x′ +̂ y

data ℤ : Set where
  _-_ : (x : ℕ) → (y : ℕ) → ℤ
  quot : ∀ {x y x′ y′} → Same x y x′ y′ → (x - y) ≡ (x′ - y′)
  trunc : {x y : ℤ} → (p q : x ≡ y) → p ≡ q
```

This allowed me to prove `right` (and thus, `surface`) with no further issues. One slight hiccup is that trying to use pattern matching caused some weird "function is not fibrant" errors, so I ended up going via the following explicit eliminator:

```
module ℤElim {ℓ} {P : ℤ → Set ℓ}
  (point* : ∀ x y → P (x - y))
  (quot* : ∀ {x y x′ y′} same → PathP (λ i → P (quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} same i)) (point* x y) (point* x′ y′))
  (trunc* : ∀ {x y} {p q : x ≡ y} → ∀ {fx : P x} {fy : P y} (eq₁ : PathP (λ i → P (p i)) fx fy) (eq₂ : PathP (λ i → P (q i)) fx fy) → PathP (λ i → PathP (λ j → P (trunc p q i j)) fx fy) eq₁ eq₂)
  where

  ℤ-elim : ∀ x → P x
  ℤ-elim (x - y) = point* x y
  ℤ-elim (quot p i) = quot* p i
  ℤ-elim (trunc p q i j) = trunc* (cong ℤ-elim p) (cong ℤ-elim q) i j
```

and so for reference, the full implementation of `_+_` using `ℤ-elim`:

```
_+_ : ℤ → ℤ → ℤ
_+_ = ℤ-elim
  (λ x y → ℤ-elim
    (λ a b → (x +̂ a) - (y +̂ b))
    (λ eq₂ → quot (inner-lemma x y eq₂))
    trunc)
  (λ {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ i → ℤ-elim
    (λ a b → quot (outer-lemma x y eq₁) i)
    (λ {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₂ j → lemma {x} {y} {x′} {y′} {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₁ eq₂ i j )
    trunc)
  (λ {_} {_} {_} {_} {x+} {y+} eq₁ eq₂ i →
    funExt λ a → λ j → trunc {x+ a} {y+ a} (ap eq₁ a) (ap eq₂ a) i j)
  where
    lemma : ∀ {x y x′ y′ a b a′ b′} → Same x y x′ y′ → Same a b a′ b′ → I → I → ℤ
    lemma {x} {y} {x′} {y′} {a} {b} {a′} {b′} eq₁ eq₂ i j = surface i j
      where
        {-
                         p   Xᵢ
                 X  ---------+---> X′

                         p₀  i
           A     X+A --------\---> X′+A
           |     |           |
          q|  q₀ |           | qᵢ
           |     |           |
        Aⱼ +    j+          [+]  <--- This is where we want to get to!
           |     |           |
           V     V       p₁  |
           A′    X+A′ -------/---> X′+A′
                             i
        -}

        X = x - y
        X′ = x′ - y′
        A = a - b
        A′ = a′ - b′

        X+A   = (x +̂ a) - (y +̂ b)
        X′+A  = (x′ +̂ a) - (y′ +̂ b)
        X+A′  = (x +̂ a′) - (y +̂ b′)
        X′+A′ = (x′ +̂ a′) - (y′ +̂ b′)

        p : X ≡ X′
        p = quot eq₁

        q : A ≡ A′
        q = quot eq₂

        p₀ : X+A ≡ X′+A
        p₀ = quot (outer-lemma x y eq₁)

        p₁ : X+A′ ≡ X′+A′
        p₁ = quot (outer-lemma x y eq₁)

        q₀ : X+A ≡ X+A′
        q₀ = quot (inner-lemma x y eq₂)

        q₁ : X′+A ≡ X′+A′
        q₁ = quot (inner-lemma x′ y′ eq₂)

        qᵢ : ∀ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i
        qᵢ = slidingLid p₀ p₁ q₀

        left : qᵢ i0 ≡ q₀
        left = refl

        right : qᵢ i1 ≡ q₁
        right = trunc (qᵢ i1) q₁

        surface : PathP (λ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i) q₀ q₁
        surface i = comp (λ j → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i)
          (λ { j (i = i0) → left j
             ; j (i = i1) → right j
             })
          (inc (qᵢ i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, in the hope that it will lure someone into solving the next piece of this puzzle.

So, I managed to prove `right`, and with it, that there is a continuous surface from `left` to `right` :

```
right : qᵢ i1 ≡ q₁
right i = comp
  (λ j → p j + A ≡ p j + A′)
  (λ { j (i = i0) → qᵢ j
     ; j (i = i1) → cong (λ ξ → quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ j + ξ) q
     }
  (inc (left i))

surface : PathP (λ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i) q₀ q₁
surface i = comp (λ j → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i)
  (λ { j (i = i0) → q₀
     ; j (i = i1) → right j
     })
  (inc (qᵢ i))

Xᵢ+Aⱼ = surface i j
```

This definition of `Xᵢ+Aⱼ` **passes the typechecker**, but fails during termination checking. Basically, all occurrences of `_+_` are marked as problematic; in particular, the ones in the definition of `right`: both the `p j + A` and `p j + A′` calls, and the congruence function in `cong (λ ξ → quot {x} {y} {x′} {y′} eq₁ j + ξ) q`.

The first two don't make much sense to me: I have already defined `_+-` for the midpoint+point and the point+point cases, and the second argument in `p j + A` and `p j + A′` are clearly points.

The third one, I am looking for suggestions on.