# Pushing a path along a pair of paths originating from its endpoints

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

Suppose I have, using the [`cubical-demo`](https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo) library, the following things in scope:

```
i : I

p0 : x ≡ y
p1 : x' ≡ y' 

q0 : x ≡ x'    
q1 : y ≡ y'
```

How do I then construct

```
q' : p0 i ≡ p1 i
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one I've come up with is I think closer to the spirit of the original problem instead of going around:

```
slidingLid : ∀ (p₀ : a ≡ b) (p₁ : c ≡ d) (q : a ≡ c) → ∀ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i
slidingLid p₀ p₁ q i j = comp (λ _ → A)
  (λ{ k (i = i0) → q j
    ; k (j = i0) → p₀ (i ∧ k)
    ; k (j = i1) → p₁ (i ∧ k)
    })
  (inc (q j))
```

This one has the very nice property that it degenerates to `q` at `i = i0` definitionally:

```
slidingLid₀ : ∀ p₀ p₁ q → slidingLid p₀ p₁ q i0 ≡ q
slidingLid₀ p₀ p₁ q = refl
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is by contracting singleton pairs with J, there might be simpler proofs though.

```
open import Cubical.PathPrelude

q' : ∀ {A : Set} (i : I) (x : A)
     x' (q0 : x ≡ x')
     y  (p0 : x ≡ y)
     y' (p1 : x' ≡ y')
     (q1 : y ≡ y') →  p0 i ≡ p1 i 
q' i x = pathJ _ (pathJ _ (pathJ _ (\ q1 → q1)))
```

Comment: Any idea why I can't eta-expand `q'`?

Comment: I realize now that `q1` is completely redundant, since it is just the transport of `q0` along `p0`/`p1`.

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question about this function's behaviour at `i0`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53166153/477476

Comment: It should be possible to eta-expand `q'` as long as you first fill in the `_`. I would replace them by ? reload and then use C-c C-s to have agda fill them in, then eta-expand.

Comment: Oh, and the reason is that if the extra variables are not in scope the unification problems coming from typechecking have a unique solution.

Comment: I've switched over to using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199767/477476) because that one seems to be more.. space-filling?

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution to this, which is more explicit that it is gluing together a prefix of `p0` (flipped), `q0`, and a prefix of `p1`:

```
open import Cubical.PathPrelude

module _ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} where
  midPath : ∀ {a b c d : A} (p₀ : a ≡ b) (p₁ : c ≡ d) → (a ≡ c) → ∀ i → p₀ i ≡ p₁ i
  midPath {a = a} {c = c} p₀ p₁ q i = begin
    p₀ i ≡⟨ transp (λ j → p₀ (i ∧ j) ≡ a) refl ⟩
    a    ≡⟨ q ⟩
    c    ≡⟨ transp (λ j → c ≡ p₁ (i ∧ j)) refl ⟩
    p₁ i ∎
```