# Equality between paths

Tags: equality, agda, cubical-type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Using the [`cubical-demo`](https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo) library, I thought the following would be trivial to prove:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
open import Cubical.PathPrelude

foo : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {x y : A} (p : x ≡ y) → trans refl p ≡ p
foo p = ?
```

But alas, it doesn't hold definitionally: trying to use `refl` fails with

```
primComp (λ _ → ;A) (~ i ∨ i) (λ { i₁ (i = i0) → ;x ; i₁ (i = i1) → p i₁ }) (refl i)
!= p i 
of type ;A
```

and I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sadly we lose some definitional equalities when using Path, because we don't know how to keep the system confluent if we were to add those reductions.

The eliminator of the `Id` type instead has the usual reduction rules.

https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo/blob/master/src/Cubical/Id.agda

In the case of the lemma you want to prove about `trans` you can find a proof at

https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo/blob/master/src/Cubical/Lemmas.agda

By the way, cubical-demo grew up organically, and we are starting fresh with hopefully a cleaner setup (altough with different primitives) at

https://github.com/agda/cubical

`cubical` has a better `Id` module for example:

https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/master/Cubical/Core/Id.agda

Comment: So should I mostly use `Id` whenever the two endpoints have the same type, instead of `Path`? Like, if I am defining a HIT, should it have `Id` constructors?

Comment: Currently we do not support HITs with Id constructors, that sounds interesting to look into though. I suppose Id does not help you much in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Saizan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53175997/477476) I looked up [the proof in `cubical-demo`](https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo/blob/7c594e4bdec2750abc78e1dfa271591496225f49/src/Cubical/Lemmas.agda#L15) and ported it to the new [`cubical`](https://github.com/agda/cubical) library. I can see how it works out (as in, I can see that the value of the given path is `x` on all three designated edges) but I don't see yet how I would come up with a similar proof for a similar situation:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
module _ where

open import Cubical.Core.Prelude

refl-compPath : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {x y : A} (p : x ≡ y) → compPath refl p ≡ p
refl-compPath {x = x} p i j = hcomp {φ = ~ j ∨ j ∨ i}
  (λ { k (j = i0) → x
     ; k (j = i1) → p k
     ; k (i = i1) → p (k ∧ j)
     })
  x
```